Wit Ai An error occurred in speech recognition
I am using api.wit.ai/speech to recognize voice messages.
They are in wav(pcm_s16le, ar 16k) format, everything worked fine for a year, but recently I started to get the error “An error occurred in speech recognition.”.
If you try to recognize the same voice message several times, then sooner or later wit will give the desired result with recognized text.
What can be the problem?
{ "code": "wit", "error": "An error occurred in speech recognition." }

